# linking to a radiobutton value, data is not binding, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

hi i need to modify my code a little bit. i have a page with a radio button list and a textarea. the textarea is populated when a users makes a radio button selection.

also, when a user makes a radio button selection the url will hold an extention in the url to show which selection index number they have selection. (i.e. ?selected=0)

http://test.com/frm_Articles.aspx?selected=0
http://test.com/frm_Articles.aspx?selected=1
http://test.com/frm_Articles.aspx?selected=2

that way they can copy the url and reference it in other websites as a link. or place it in their favorites.

**the problem is,** if you grab the url and open a new browser, the page does not pass the value and databind accordingly. no radio buttons or content appear on the page. 
must be the postback logic i think???

what's working:

1. when i launch the website the radio buttons appear and index 0 is set
2. when i select radio buttons the correct data displays and urls linking to radio button values display in browser (i.e. http://test.com/test.aspx?selected=2)
3. if i cut and paste pointer urls within the same browser then correct data is rendered

what doesn't work (everything that deal with an false PostBack):

1.when i launch website no data within the textarea apprears even though the radio button is set to 0 index and is visiable.
2. if i cut and paste pointer url into a new browser, text area and radio buttons do not display.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {

                int selected;


                if (Request.QueryString["selected"] != null)
                {


                    if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["selected"], out selected))
                    {   


                        RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = selected;
                        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();


                    }



                }
                else
                {

                    int firstart = 0;      

                    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = firstart;
                    RadioButtonList1.DataBind();   

                }

            }


    }


    protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

  //    

    }
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
        e.Command.Parameters["@URL_FK"].Value =  Session["URL_PK"];


        }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }


    }


    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


           string strRedirect;
           strRedirect = "test.aspx?selected=" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex;  
           Response.Redirect(strRedirect);

    }


}
```

Comment: If loop works only for boolean value not consider any int as true

Comment: thanks for your input. could you further explain your comment? i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my SqlDataSource1_Selecting method was the issue. i used another approach and my code worked.

Answer (score 1):

In your code at `Page_Load` event before this line

`RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = selected;`

you should bind RadioButtonList1. after binding RadioButtonList you can set `SelectedIndex`.